# Kotlin - Como reproduzir o efeito de "lateinit" em um "var" de uma interface?

Tags: interface, propriedade, kotlin

Eu tenho uma interface chamada `UserManager` que possui um *var* do tipo `User`

```
interface UserManager {

    var user:User

    /* ... */
}
```

e uma classe chamada `UserManagerImpl` que implementa `UserManager`

```
class UserManagerImpl : UserManager {

    override var user: User // = uma instancia default de User deve ser fornecida

    /* ... */
}
```

A minha dúvida é a seguinte

Como permitir que uma classe possa *setar* um `User` no `UserManager()` a qualquer momento (* ie * eu não forneceria um `User` *default*, mas deixaria que outra classe criasse e *setasse* um `User` quando fosse necessário) ?

**Observações**

1. Interfaces não possuem propriedades **lateinit**
2. Eu gostaria que a classe `User` fosse **não nula**, portanto, eu não queria que `null` fosse o valor default para `user` (*i.e* fazendo `var user: User? = null` )
3. Eu gostaria de acessar os campos diretamente ao invés de usar métodos da interface (*i.e* chamar userManager.user para retornar um usuário, ao invés de  userManager.getUser() )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente não é possível definir uma propriedade `lateinit` em uma interface.

Mas é possível definir essa propriedade como `lateinit` na subclasse.

Ficaria algo como:

```
interface UserManager {
    var user: User
}

class UserManager Impl: UserManager {
    override lateinit var user: User

    fun initUser(): UserManager = apply { user = User() }
}

println("${UserManagerImpl().initUser().user}")
```

Irá gerar o resultado que deseja.

---

Uma outra alternativa seria usar propriedades delegadas com `lazy`, mas isso vai obrigar que a propriedade seja imutável, mas pode lhe servir em outro contexto:

```
interface UserManager {
    val user: User
}

class UserManager Impl: UserManager {
    override val user: User by lazy {
        User()
    }
}

println("${UserManagerImpl().user}")
```